# Regularity of solution of simple Elliptic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

Let $u: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a solution of the elliptic PDE

$$ \sum_{i,j}^n a_{ij} D_i D_j u = 0,$$

where the $a_{ij} $ are constants.

Then we know by regularity theory (e.g. Evans Chapter 6) that $u \in C^\infty$.

But I also read that we have the following estimate:

$$ \sup_{B_{R/2}}|D^k u(x)| \leq \frac{C}{R^k} \sup_{B_R}|u(x)|.$$

How do we get this last estimate?

Comment: What exactly is $D^k$?

Comment: @K.defaoite kth order partial derivative

Comment: Where did you find this result?

Comment: @K.defaoite in pde lecture

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a link or something to this lecture?